# Could an infinite spinning windmill create endless electricity?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, power, perpetual-motion

This is not so much a question about if this idea is physically possibly, but more a question of if it was possible.

If a magnet could somehow push a windmill around at a constant speed continuously, could that generate a constant stream of electricity?

Comment: Sure, but the "somehow" here is important.   It will take more energy to do the "somehow" than would be gained by the windmill.

Comment: Yes, but magnets can't do that.

Answer (score 2):

So long as your electric generator is spinning then you will get electricity out of it

The BIG problem with this construction is conservation of energy.

You will have to supply energy to the windmill in order to get electric energy out of it.

So to get an "infinite" amount of energy out of your windmill youd have to supply more than that to keep it running (conservation of energy and the fact that nothing is 100% efficient)

Make sense?